# Constructible models of New Foundations?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, set-theory, new-foundations, constructibility

Hi all! Is there anything like Gödel's constructible universe for New Foundations?

More precisely, I would like a process for taking a model $M$ of NF, and using it to build a model $L \subseteq M$ of NF with the property that every set in $L$ is defined by a (stratified) first-order formula with quantifiers ranging over $M$. (Edited; see the comments for a discussion of some issues surrounding this definition.)

Anything not exactly that, but along those lines, would also be of interest. I would also be interested in hearing about such results for non-well-founded set theories other than NF. Has this been done? Is it possible?

I'm wondering because I am trying to build this sort of constructible model for a naïve set theory that I am studying. I haven't figured out how to apply the methods used for models of ZF to models of naïve set theory. I'm guessing that similar issues might apply in working with NF, because both theories are primarily distinguished by their use of a powerful comprehension axiom.

Thank you!

Comment: Nick: It is an open problem (or depending on your optimism, it was, up to a few weeks ago) whether NF is consistent. We certainly do not understand the structure of NF models well enough (or even of possible NF models, granting consistency) to answer this. NFU is better understood, and still nothing is known about "canonical" NFU models. 

Comment: I'm probably just ignorant, but: NF isn't known to be equiconsistent with ZF, which means that nobody has a model of NF. So doesn't that make it impossible to start with such a model M and use it to build your other model L?

Comment: @Andres: You beat me to it. What is the event you're referring to in "up to a few weeks ago?"

Comment: @Ben: http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2012-November/016758.html Randall has a privately circulated manuscript, that he's been editing. He'll most likely send you the latest version if you email him about it.

Comment: The second paragraph of the question, beginning "More precisely," isn't exactly what you meant, because it can be satisfied by defining $L$ to be $V$, the whole universe. Your definability requirement is satisfied because you allow parameters from $L$; any set $s$ (in $V$) has a trivial stratified definition with a parameter from $V$, namely $s$ itself: $s=\{x:x\in s\}$. The essence of "genuine" $L$ (as opposed to my phony $L$ defined as $V$) is that the parameters in the definition of $s$ must come "before" $s$, in some (presumably ordinal-indexed) hierarchy.

Comment: Some thoughts on how to approach this or how to make the question more specific. I suspect that there is no "iterative conception" or "predicative view" that makes perfect sense for NF, so $L$ might not be the right idea. However, I think it makes sense to ask whether NF has a some kind of a "prime model." Perhaps there is some extension NF+? such that the (parameter-free) definable elements of a model also model NF+?...

Comment: @Andres: it sounds like you've essentially answered my question, with the answer being "nobody's done it;" correct? Also, thanks for sharing the announcement of that exciting result! @Ben: Yeah, but you can assume that a model exists and then play with it to make new models. Maybe you already know this, and maybe I'm missing something. But e.g., assume that a model of ZFC exists, and use said model to build a model where the continuum hypothesis fails, and you've effectively proven that if ZFC is consistent (a model exists) then ZFC doesn't prove CH (there is a model of ZFC where CH fails).

Comment: @Andreas and @Francois: You both raise similar and important issues with the way I've framed my question. In particular, you're right, Andreas, that the requirement I stated is trivially fulfilled. Thanks for pointing that out. Here's a possible alternate formulation. Given a model $M$, call a set $x \in M$ "definable" iff $x$ is defined by a (stratified) formula, with quantifiers ranging over $M$, whose parameters are definable. Do you think that makes sense of the question?

Comment: The iterative conception here is as follows. Stage 0 is sets definable by formulas without parameters. Stage $n+1$ is sets definable by formulas with parameters from stage $n$.

Comment: Also (sorry about the fourth comment!): can anybody explain what Holmes' result (if correct) says (if anything) about the relative consistency of NF and, say, ZF or ZFC? (Should this be a new question?)

Comment: @Nick: This is addressed in Randall's announcement. If Randall's argument is correct, ZF proves the consistency of NF. In fact, NF is equiconsistent with Mac Lane set theory, which is strictly weaker than Zermelo's set theory, which is strictly weaker than ZF.

Comment: @Nick: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117371/how-to-measure-the-strength-of-zermelo-over-bounded-zermelo

Comment: @Nick: Maybe I'm missing some subtlety related to stratification, but it seems to me that anything definable from definable parameters would itself be definable.  Just take the definition from definable parameters and replace each parameter by a circumlocution using its definition.  (Does the replacement ruin stratifiability??)

Comment: @Andreas: So your thought is that every definable set would already be defined in the first stage? That seems like a distinct possibility. If $a$ is a definable parameter defined by $\psi(x)$, replace $x \in a$ with $\psi(x)$, and $a \in x$ with... ? Let me know if you have an answer there. As for your question about stratification, truly no clue.

Comment: @Nick: The obvious replacement for $a\in x$ would be $(\exists y)\,(\forall z)\,((z\in y\iff\psi(z))\land y\in x)$.  It looks stratified to me (assuming f course that $\psi$ is stratified), and the stratifying type assignment would give $x$ a type higher by 2 than the argument $z$ of $\psi$, which looks right.

Comment: @Andreas: That looks right to me. Thank you for working this out with me. So perhaps what I really want to ask for is simply a model of NF wherein every set is definable by a stratified formula without parameters. Does that seem sensible?

Comment: @Nick: Your last suggestion looks sensible to me.  Unfortunately,I have no idea what the answer is.  It might need an NF expert.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks; I'll edit the question. I'd like to use the trick you described for eliminating parameters in a proof I'm writing. Is it something you thought of in this thread, and if so may I cite your comments here? Thank you!

Comment: @Nick: The idea of eliminating definable parameters in favor of their definitions is not mine.  I'm pretty sure it existed before I was born, but I don't know who first used it. My best guess is Tarski, but that's only a guess.  I think you can safely refer to it as "well known" in your proof.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. I'm also a person with no masters and no experience doing any research job and am probably missing some information. That's probably why I can't figure out what your question is. I trust that a lot of people can understand it and it was written it a way that made it clear to them what you were asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My impression is that a reconstruction of L in NF is not very
satisfactory.  One version of L's construction, following Jensen, is to take the
rudimentary set functions and iterate them under composition and unions along 
the (von Neumann) ordinals.  However not all the rudimentary functions can be given a stratified definition.  Thomas Forster remedies this and defines a list of strat.rud. functions and mimicks the Jensen process using these to build a strat.rud. closed model S.  However choice fails in S, but more significantly, S has a canonical wellorder (that of construction) but initial segments of the graph of this well order are only unstratified, and thus are not in S. In short the model S cannot "construct itself" in the way that "V=L" is shown to hold in L. Worse still, there is no total order even of $V_\omega$ (let alone a wellorder) in S.

The problem seems to be that one can iterate the strat.rud functions along wellorderings, but there is no way in general to compare the results: one does not have in general a Mostowski-Shepherdson Collapsing Lemma in NF to "transitivize and compare" the differing hierarchies so produced, because there is insufficient induction. (The latter problem would seem to raise its head whatever version of L's construction one used.)

Forster's article is in Contemporary Mathematics, vol 36, 2004. You may want to check out his webpage, which lists publications of himself and his research group. Dang's thesis to be found there (I think) looks to be relevant.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it for NF, but there is a good notion of constructible model of the theory CUS of Church, that has a universal set.   But that's really just a trick of the light, since the big sets of CUS are magicked into existence by a coding trick.  None of that is in print, so there is nothing i can cite.  Sorry!